# i am getting no return tags error on google webmaster tool

Tags: google-search-console, google-crawlers, hreflang

Hi i have put this code on my website www.eliquidsnow.com

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-nz" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gr" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-dk" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-bg" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-pl" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-se" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-nl" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-fr" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-it" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-hr" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ie" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ee" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-mt" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-de" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-sk" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-at" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-pt" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-hu" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-lt" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />

<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
```

basicaLLy i want to show this website for all the english speakers in the worl now i m getting this error from google webmaster tools 
on international taargetting option i get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w8Hk.png

```
'en'- no return tags
'en-gr'- no return tags
'en-bg'- no return tags
```

and it goes for all the languages

i need to sort this problem out so the website can be seen around the world to whoever speaks english

thank you

Comment: Hey, what Google expects if you spamming your site with all this hrflangs is a different URL for every of this tags. For example =
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-nz" href="https://nz.eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://au.eliquidsnow.com/" />
What you want is to tell Google, that you page is for english speaking people. You could do this like this: <html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">. That should be enough for Google to get it.

Comment: k i have added that thank you so much i have been looking for an answer for so long also i m from uk is there like a uk for example en-gb?

Comment: <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://eliquidsnow.com/" />

This is enougth for the markup.